# Different responses to getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my app I use Context in a class that handles all the requests to my apps SharedPreferences, the relevant part of the class is the constructor:

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
public AppSettings(Context context){
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}
```

Within my initial **Activity** I can set and read the parameters just fine using some other methods in the class, I call the context using **getApplicationContext()** from within a **doInBackground()** call of a class extending **AsyncTask**:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
        AppSettings as = new AppSettings(context);
        ...
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but when I try to recover the settings in the next Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppSettings as = AppSettings(getApplicationContext());
    }
    ...
}
```

I get an error in Eclipse that says:

> The method AppSettings(Context) is undefined for the type MainActivity

My understanding about the getApplicationContext is that it should give me the global Context of the app, but apparently in each case it is returning something different. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errr.. don't you mean

```
AppSettings as = new AppSettings(getApplicationContext()); //<-- missed the "new"
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Two hours of reading and looking at it and missed that... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, happens to everyone :)